# French equivalent of the hyperbolic "The best, hands down, bar none, period!"

Tags: expressions

> The greatest invention of all time, **hands down, bar none, period!**

This is a hyperbolic expression, with each of the three phrases separated by commas serving to emphasise the idea of something deserving superlatives.

I wonder what is the idiomatic French equivalent of this expression?

Comment: Hi. Could you provide some links explaining it in English? That can be interesting for people like me who is not so fluent.

Comment: @lemon Hi. I don't think there is a dictionary entry covering all these three as a single set expression. As for the meaning of each, tlombart offers a comprehensive explanation. :) Another variant is: "hands down, bar none, end of story!" or  "hands down, bar none, the best!".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **period !** one is the easiest to translate : you can say **point final !** to close an argument in French. This is the same as it is in English, it refers to the punctuation mark, and can be used similarly.

> Je t'ai demandé d'aller te coucher, **point final** !

**Hands down** actually translates to the opposite in French : **haut la main**. **Facilement**, or its more familiar form **facile** are equally used I guess. Another translation could be **les doigts dans le nez**, although it doesn't fit in this context of superlative.

> Il a réussi le test **haut la main**
>   C'est **facilement** le garçon le plus beau de la pièce !
>   Il les a **facile** tous battus
>   J'ai réussi **les doigts dans le nez**

Regarding **bar none**, the easiest translation is **sans exception**.

> C'est le meilleur, **sans exception**

Now, if you want to say all three as an idiomatic expression in French, I don't believe there is an super-hyperbolic expression consisting of 3 other hyperbolic expressions. I guess you will have to stick to only one of these... This is my best attempt at a literal translation :

> C'est sans exception la meilleure chose jamais inventée, point final !

Comment: Hi. How do you feel about "C'est ***de loin*** la meilleure chose jamais inventée, ***un point c'est tout !***"? :)

Comment: I'd also suggest "point barre", but I also like Alone-zee solution. Anyway "il les a facile tous battus" is not correct.

Comment: @Distic Hi. Do you think "point à la ligne !" works just as well?

Comment: @Alone-zee : Yes, even if I prefer if with a comma : "point, à la ligne". But it exists without it also (just because people say it to fast).

Comment: @Distic facile is commonly used in southern France (around Nice anyway) as a shortcut to facilement ! grammatically i agree it doesn't make any sense and it is a very familiar thing to say ! not to be used anytime else than when with friends !

Comment: @Alone-zee **c'est de loin** is a great translation i didn't think of ! it would be corresponding to **hands down** in English, i guess. **un point c'est tout** and **point, à la ligne** are variants of **point final** and all three mean the same and can be used similarly. **point, à la ligne** strangely reminds me of a dictation exercise and therefore i'm not sure it would fit the hyperbolic context here. **à la ligne** also suggests something else is coming after ! another paragraph or statement ! whatsoever it is very much understandable

Comment: @Distic I agree with tlombart here. *Facile* used as an adverb (for *facilement*) is common colloquial French, and not only in Southern France. [E.g.](http://www.tierce-magazine.com/breve1-pid157-cid45210-tison-madrik-gagne-en-bon-poulain.html) *Jean-Michel Baudouin a déclaré au micro d'Equidia : "L'autre jour, **il a gagné facile**. C'est encore le cas ici. Il a eu une course sage..."*

Comment: @Jiliagre and tlombart. In this case, please just indicate in the answer that it is only colloquial.

Comment: *Sans exception* is quite odd here. Neither *c'est le meilleur, sans exception* nor *c'est sans exception la meilleure chose...* are idiomatic. *Sans exception* normally apply to a whole, a group a people or things, not a single person or thing. Here is how it is used in French: *ils sont tous bons, sans exception*.

Answer (score 7):

> C'est de loin la plus grande invention de tous les temps, [il n'y a pas photo](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_n%E2%80%99y_a_pas_photo) !

Comment: Hi. What do you think about mixing and matching "de loin" and "il n'y a pas photo"? "C'est ***de loin*** la meilleure chose jamais inventée, ***il n'y a pas photo !***"

Comment: It sounds good.

Comment: +1 for connecting (just as ["hands down"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hands_down) does in English) the notion of an easy win to the "Sport of Kings."