# Pourquoi on omet le « de » dans « Il n'y a pas photo »

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, négation, formulation-idiomatique

Je sais que l'expression est bien

> Il n'y a pas photo

par contre, je me demande pourquoi il n'y a pas de « de », ce qui devrait être là selon les règles normales. Devrais-je content avec le fait que ce soit idiomatique, ou est-ce qu'il y a un autre explication ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Selon le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_n%E2%80%99y_a_pas_photo), il s'agit d'une locution avec le sens très spécifique et différent de ce qui est généralement signifié par *il n'y a pas de photo*:

> **il n’y a pas photo** \il n‿j‿a pa fo.to\ (se conjugue → voir la conjugaison de avoir)
> (Figuré) (Impersonnel) Il n’y a aucun doute possible ; c’est clair, évident.
> [...]
> **Notes**
> Pour ce sens, on ne dit pas *il n’y a pas **de** photo*, qui signifie seulement qu’il n’y a aucune photographie.

Notons, que l'expression ne signifie pas littéralement qu'il n'existe pas de photo, par exemple [voir ici](https://www.caminteresse.fr/culture/pourquoi-dit-on-il-ny-a-pas-photo-1196495/) :

> La précision étant de mise pour ne pas fâcher les parieurs qui pourraient s’estimer lésés, les directeurs des compétitions ont recours à la photographie depuis près de cinquante ans pour départager les concurrents. **Inversement, si le résultat est net et que les chevaux arrivent avec un écart significatif, « il n’y a pas [besoin de] photo » !**

Comment: Oui justement - je sais qu'elle est une expression, mais je suppose que je demande pourquoi le « de » a été oublié, puisque ce n'est pas « correct » selon les règles de négation. Je devrais me contenter du fait que souvent les expressions ne suivent pas les règles à la lettre peut-être.

Comment: @DerekAllums il s'agit de l'expression raccourcie, mais qui signifie à la base une autre chose, comme *il n'y a pas besoin de photo*. Elle ne signifie pas literallement, que la photo n'a pas été prise.

Comment: *Il n'y a pas [besoin de] photo* -> *Il n'y a pas photo* voilà ce que je cherche merci !

Comment: A priori l'expression est une allusion à la [photo- finish](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo-finish) souvent utilisé aussi dans les courses de chevaux.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27263/french-equivalent-of-the-hyperbolic-the-best-hands-down-bar-none-period/27265#27265